# Android: Detect opened keyboard, onApplyWindowListener not working

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin

I am trying to hide one specific button at the bottom of my layout when the keyboard is opened, in order to make more view available for the user.

With the release of `androidx.core:core-ktx:1.5.0-alpha02` google (finally) added a method called `insets.isVisible(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.ime())` which returns a boolean whether the keyboard is opened or clicked.

I am using a base class `EmailFragment` where I set the function in order to achieve the above written functionality. My problem is that my `ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(view)` gets never called (no toast etc).

I've also tried to set `ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(view)` directly in the used Fragments, but that changed nothing.

My min API is 21, in my AndroidManifest.XML I have `android:windowSoftInputMode = adjustResize`

### Code

```
abstract class EmailFragment<out T: ViewDataBinding>(
    layout: Int,
    // ... some other stuff that is not necessary for the question
) : BaseFragment<T>(layout) {
    // ... some other stuff that is not necesarry for the question

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        hideButton(view)
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState)
    }

    
    private fun hideButton(view: View) {
        ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(view) { v, insets ->
            val isKeyboardVisible = insets.isVisible(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.ime())
            if (isKeyboardVisible) {
                btn.visibility = View.GONE
                Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "KEYBOARD OPEN", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            } else {
                btn.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "KEYBOARD CLOSED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }

            // Return the insets to keep going down this event to the view hierarchy
            insets
        }
    }
}
```

### Fragment that inherits from EmailFragment (one out of five)

```
class CalibrateRepairMessageFragment(
    //... some other stuff that is not necessary for this question
) : EmailFragment<FragmentCalibrateRepairMessageBinding>(
    R.layout.fragment_calibrate_repair_message,
    //... some other stuff that is not necessary for this question
) {
    //... some other stuff that is not necessary for this question

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        //... some other stuff that is not necessary for this question
    }
```

### Screenshot 1 (censored)

[image]

### Screenshot 2, not working (censored)

[image]

I know that using `android:windowSoftInputMode = adjustPen` makes my button "invisible" but then I cannot scroll anymore, big sad..

Another solution could be that the keyboard just overlaps the button, but I have no clue how to do that...

I appreciate every help, thank you.

Comment: What version of Android you are using for testing?

Comment: @PankajKumar I'm testing it with the emulator that runs on Android 10

Comment: Have you tested it on Android 11? And this feature is not released yet, so I would recommend you to wait for some time, till then use the old way.

Comment: @PankajKumar what is the old way? All of those "old way approaches" don't work reliably

Comment: Are you using adjustPan in activity tag? I found this reddit https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/id30z3/windowinsetscompat/

Comment: @PankajKumar No I said that I use adjustresize.. When I use adjustpen I would no longer have the need to use the listener because adjustpen WOULD ALREADY ignore the button. But with adjustpen you cannot scroll anymore in scrollview.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221469/discussion-between-pankaj-kumar-and-andrew).

Comment: @Andrew did you find solution for this? I'm facing the same issue?

Comment: @dakshbhatt21 Unfortunately not, as said above, this function is either 1. Not working at all (because alpha) or 2. only working for devices with Android 11. I will try to investigate later in this, but I have no hope that this will ever work..

Comment: @Andrew gotcha, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I was able to get this to work by:

1. Adding `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` to `Activity` tag in manifest
2. Setting `OnApplyWindowInsetsListener` on `window.decorView`.

However, this had unfortunate side effects to the statusbar which means that OP's comment ("I have no hope that this will ever work") is probably accurate. Hopefully it will work when it graduates from alpha and beta.

Comment: I got this working following your guidelines but I dont know how to null the listener in kotlin. I need to declare the var at the top as private var decore: ?? Im not sure, so I can access it and null it in the onDestroyView otherwise it will cause a null when I move to another fragment.